# IIS configuration to modify 'maximum content length' using power shell

Tags: windows, powershell, iis, automation, registry

I am trying to configure the value of "maximum content length" to "30000000" (approx. 28.6 MB). My script is as follows-

```
 cd C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv
 ./appcmd set config /section:requestfiltering /requestlimits.maxallowedcontentlength:30000000

 If ((Get-WindowsFeature Web-Filtering).Installed -EQ $true) {
   Get-Website | Foreach-Object {
       $site = $_
      [PSCustomObject]@{
      "Site" = $site.Name
      "maxAllowedContentLength" = (((Get-WebConfiguration -Filter 'system.webServer/security/requestFiltering' -PSPath "IIS:\sites\$($site.Name)").requestLimits).Attributes | Where-Object Name -EQ 'maxAllowedContentLength').Value
      }
     }
    }
```

Script executes successfully but when I check with the 'Internet Service Manager' no changes reflects there. I am wondering is there any fault in the script? Because it returns no error to troubleshoot.

Comment: You might ask this in a dedicated forum [IIS Forum](https://forums.iis.net).

Comment: Won't help updating server-level configs if its also set on the individual sites: `./appcmd set config /section:...` -> `./appcmd set config "siteName" /section:...`

Comment: could you please share what is your exact retirement? do you want to set at the server level or site level? i tried your script which is working fine at my side. [image](https://i.imgur.com/sXDcd2P.png)

Comment: I need the changes to be applied on site level but the script applying changes on server level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me to figure out the solution:
     ./appcmd set config "WebsiteName "/section:requestfiltering /requestlimits.maxallowedcontentlength:30000000 /commit:site

Comment: If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.